# How do I set a flex-container to be the width of its flex-items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with `justify-content: flex-start`. There ends up being overflow on the right side due to the flex items taking less space than the size of the container.

Aside from setting an explicit width on the flex-container, is there a way of just having the equivalent of `width: auto` to remove the overflow?

Comment: Flex boxes are pretty damn tricky… and they still have a lot of work to go before they are actually reliable. But this link can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: Hmm...can you [show a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: you are talking of "overflow" and "less space" but you probably mean "underflow" and "less space" or "overflow" and "more space". clarify your question

Comment: Any answers for this??? I've created a fiddle to demonstrate a similiar issue i'm facing: http://jsfiddle.net/fxz6o726/

Comment: In the past, I've seen this accomplished with `flex-basis: auto`, but it seems like we're in a transitional state where Blink is preparing to add `flex-basis: content`, which should accomplish exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: If you use `display: inline-flex;` and you set for the same element: `width: min-content;` then you have the same size as with `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 128):

If you mean you want the container to be the width of the items, rather than the items expanding to the container width...

You may be able to get that by changing `display:flex` to `display:inline-flex`

Comment: `inline-flex` doesn't help in my case, and actually, should it? Isn't that impossible? Like when you set `inline-block` for container and `width: 100%` for block items inside, the container won't resize to its `max-width` but rather container and items will stay with minimal possible widths. Wouldn't it work similar for flexbox?

Comment: `display:inline-flex` solved a similar issue in my case

Comment: Worked perfect in my case. Just was required additional min-width="100%"

Comment: This method only works if your flex items fit in just **one row**.

Answer (score 35):

1. `width: min-content` (CSS3 "intrinsic" as opposed to "extrinsic")
2. `display: inline-flex` if you don't care whether it's inline

If you use `width: min-content` on a paragraph, the longest word determines the width.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-inline-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.width-min-content {
  width: min-content;
}

.row-direction {
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #3cf;
 }
.col-direction {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0.0625rem solid magenta;
}
```

```html
flex
<div class='flex-container row-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>
<div class='flex-container col-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>
<br>
flex width: min-content
<div class='flex-container width-min-content row-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>
<div class='flex-container width-min-content col-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>
<br>
inline-flex
<div class='flex-inline-container row-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>

<div class='flex-inline-container col-direction'>
  <input />
  <input type='datetime-local'>
</div>
```

Comment: width: min-content shrinks the width by wrapping the content. width: max-content shrinks the width until it would be necessary to wrap the content, and then stops shrinking.

Comment: this wont work if there is margin-left.

Answer (score 24):

This one worked for me on the same inline-flex (or flex) element:

```
   width: fit-content;
```

Comment: There is no such property for width.

Comment: @KonradGałęzowski 
Please see this caniuse page:
https://caniuse.com/?search=width%3A%20fit-content%3B

Comment: ... and [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#values), and [w3c](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-sizing-4/#width-height-keywords)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Mahks, you can [make the flex container inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984488/how-do-i-set-a-flex-container-to-be-the-width-of-its-flex-items/25903945#25903945). But if laying it inline is not suitable for your layout, an alternative is to float the flex container (not the flex items).

[Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width) will shrink-wrap to fit their contents, and this is no different for a block-level flex container. An inline-level flex container behaves similarly to an [inline-block box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width) when laid out in its parent inline formatting context, which means it will also shrink to fit its contents by default.

Comment: If you're supporting older Firefox browsers, using floats will cause Bad Things (tm) to happen (see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660699)

Answer (score 1):

not sure about your question, but:

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/jn45P/

you just need to enable the flexibility on the flex items, using `flex-grow:1;` to fill up the space

```
<div class="o">
    <div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
</div>

<div class="o flex">
    <div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
</div>

div.o
{
    border:2px red solid;
    padding:2px;
    width:500px;
    flex-direction:row;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}

div.o > div
    {border:2px red solid;margin:2px;}

div.o.flex > div
    {flex:1 1 auto;} /* enable flexibility on the flex-items */
```

Comment: That resizes the items to fit the container, rather than the other way around.